# Как сформировать документ для печати и отправки по почте в формате А4

Tags: pdf, php, email, doc

Нужно на php на лету создавать документы с данными из базы mysql для печати и отправки по почте. В документе будет логотип, стандартная шапка, потом табличные данные и стандартная подпись. Если в стилях указать подходящую ширину, то на почту этот документ в каком виде придет? Не развалится всё построение? Может можно создать вордовский doc и pdf средствами php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.pdf.php либо использовать данную библиотеку: - не везде она есть и можно её установить, + скорость работы выше

либо http://www.fpdf.org/ FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: А если обычный html отправить по почте, его потом нельзя будет отправить на печать? Просто не знаю, стоит ли заморачиваться с pdf

Comment: конечно можно, ты что письма никогда не отправлял?

Comment: Просто надо чтобы письмо пришло в формате А4 и не развалилось, чтобы на печать с ящика отправлять. Просто я ни разу не печатал электронные письма, поэтому не знаю, как они себя поведут.